# Upstart failing to initialize a gunicorn server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, webserver, gunicorn, upstart

I am trying to start an instance of a server running gunicorn. Here is my upstart script:

```
 expect daemon

 script
     cd /opt/app/live/srv/poi_proxy
     exec /usr/local/bin/gunicorn server:app -c /etc/gunicorn.conf
 end script
```

And here is the gunicorn config file:

```
 bind =  '0.0.0.0:80'
 workers = 3
 worker_class = 'gevent'
```

The problem i'm having is that when running the command through the command prompt the server starts without issue. However when using the upstart script it generates a defunct process for each of the children.

Also i believe the path has to do something with it. When starting the server through the command line if i do:

```
 cd /opt/app/live/srv/poi_proxy
 sudo /usr/local/bin/gunicorn server:app -c /etc/gunicorn.conf
```

It works fine, however:

```
 sudo /usr/local/bin/gunicorn /opt/app/live/srv/poi_proxy/server:app -c /etc/gunicorn.conf
```

I am face with the same problem as when using upstart
Any idea of what could be wrong or how to fix it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like part of the problem here is you have expect daemon in the upstart config file but you are not calling gunicorn in the daemon mode. This should causes the pid to be reported incorrectly and the initctl stop command to hang.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Given your upstart script you have to instruct gunicorn to daemonize.